# special character (@) in data string producing error in dataview rowfilter

Tags: vb.net

I have a data table loaded with data. A column contains the string value "Insurance @ 4_25%".

Creating a dataview rowfilter as:

```
    Property Expense as string = "Insurance @ 4_25%"        
    dv.rowfilter = "Expense = " & Expense
```

I get the error "SyntaxErrorException was unhandled. Cannot interpret token '@' at position 21."

When I apply the data value to the property I use the .toString. This column also does not contain any string delimiters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx), you use single quotes as string delimeters.

```
dv.RowFilter = "Expense = '" & Expense & "'"
```